# How to split lines with mixed parts

Tags: python, regex

I have text lines constructed by one of template:

1. The song's title (singer) (the year of song).
2. The song's title (then singer (the year of song)).

The difference between templates is the year of song **inside or outside** of singer's parentheses.

I want split every line into three parts:

1. The song's title
2. Singer
3. The year of song

**Small example**

```
Ring Ring (ABBA (1973))
Waterloo (ABBA) (1974)
If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die (Hello Saferide) (2005)
My Best Friend (Hello Saferide (2005))
```

I try use RexExp with logical OR

```py
import re

the_lines = ("Ring Ring (ABBA (1973))",
             "Waterloo (ABBA) (1974)",
             "If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die (Hello Saferide) (2005)",
             "My Best Friend (Hello Saferide (2005))",
             )
pattern = r"((.*) \((.*)\) \((\d*)\))|((.*) \((.*\((\d*)\))\))"

for line in the_lines:
    title, artist, year = re.split(pattern, line)
    print(title, artist, year)
```

But this result is [redundant](https://pythex.org/?regex=((.*)%20%5C((.*)%5C)%20%5C((%5Cd*)%5C))%7C((.*)%20%5C((.*%5C((%5Cd*)%5C))%5C))&test_string=Ring%20Ring%20(ABBA%20(1973))%0A%0AWaterloo%20(ABBA)%20(1974)%0A%0AIf%20I%20Don%E2%80%99t%20Write%20This%20Song%20Someone%20I%20Love%20Will%20Die%20(Hello%20Saferide)%20(2005)%0A%0AMy%20Best%20Friend%20(Hello%20Saferide%20(2005))&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), it get 8 groups.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem because you have not provided code for us to run.

Comment: I make link to https://pythex.org. There are regexp and sample lines.

Comment: We saw your link.

Comment: If you would like to ask Python questions, providing Python code would be helpful. Regex can be used in any language

Comment: In any case, simple solution seems like checking if 2-4 groups are None, and if so, use 5-8

Comment: Make 2 Regexes instead of 1 and check which one matches. Typically it doesn't matter if you have to write 2 lines of code.

Comment: You can just conditionally check for a closing parenthesis after the singer: `(?P<title>.*) \((?P<artist>.*?)\)? \((?P<year>\d+)\)` or without the named groups `(.*) \((.*?)\)? \((\d+)\)`

Comment: The code is added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `split()` and `strip()` to get the result:

```
s = """Ring Ring (ABBA (1973))
Waterloo (ABBA) (1974)
If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die (Hello Saferide) (2005)
My Best Friend (Hello Saferide (2005))"""

s = [[word.strip(")") for word in line.split(" (")] for line in s.split("\n")]

print(*s, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
['Ring Ring', 'ABBA', '1973']
['Waterloo', 'ABBA', '1974']
['If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die', 'Hello Saferide', '2005']
['My Best Friend', 'Hello Saferide', '2005']
```

1. `s.split("\n")` get each line in text
2. for each line, `line.split(" (")` return a list of `[title, singer, year))]` or `[title, singer), year)]`
3. for each list, `word.strip(")")` strip `)` from singer and year.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
import re

s = '''
Ring Ring (ABBA (1973))
Waterloo (ABBA) (1974)
If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die (Hello Saferide) (2005)
My Best Friend (Hello Saferide (2005))
'''


f = re.findall(r"(.*)\s\((.*?)\)?\s\((\d{4})\)",s)
print(*f,sep='\n')
```

```
('Ring Ring', 'ABBA', '1973')
('Waterloo', 'ABBA', '1974')
('If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die', 'Hello Saferide', '2005')
('My Best Friend', 'Hello Saferide', '2005')
```

Comment: Thank you, very easy and clean regexp

Answer (score 2):

You don’t really need REs with your specification, for each line, it looks like you can use `artist_song_year = line.split("(")`, then an additional cleanup step like `artist_song_year = [item.strip(")").strip(")") for item in artist_song_year]`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python:

```
text = """Ring Ring (ABBA (1973))
Waterloo (ABBA) (1974)
If I Don’t Write This Song Someone I Love Will Die (Hello Saferide) (2005)
My Best Friend (Hello Saferide (2005))"""
text = text.split("\n")
songs = {}
for song in text:
    name = song.split("(")[0]
    band = song.split("(")[1].split(" ")[0]
    year = song.split("(")[2]
    band = band.replace(")","")
    year = year.replace(")","")
    print("band",band,"year",year,"song",name)
    songs[name] = {"year":year,"band":band}
print(songs)
```